# How to include track bar in asp.net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know how to add a track bar in a page I want to get values from user from the track bar. I want to get the % 0-100. I would like to get some code for that thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jquery UI slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/ with ajax and [WebMethod] if necessary